# vb.net Loading Images from Access Database to DataTable?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, image, ms-access

So I have a MS Access Database with 1 table (Records) and 2 fields in it ("RecordID" (Number), which is the primary key, and "LowRes" (OLE Object) which is a low Resolution image). There are about 100 records.

I/m trying to load the Access Table into a DataTable (ID_Table) in VB.net.

Code so far:

```
    Dim cnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=SBS2257_ID.accdb;"
    Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT [RecordID], [LowRes] FROM [Records];"
    Using CN As New OleDbConnection(cnString)
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand(theQuery, CN)
        Using objDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
            Dim ID_Table As New DataTable
            CN.Open()
            Dim pictureData As Byte() = DirectCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
            Dim picture As Image = Nothing
            Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream(pictureData)
                picture = Image.FromStream(stream)
                objDataAdapter.Fill(ID_Table)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

However the "DirectCast" command fails when I tell it to look at more then 1 field in my SQL statement with a datatype mismatch (if I just do [LowRes] it does not throw a error). However, I get stuck again when trying to apply the result to the table via the objDataAdapter, it doesnt fill the table with anything? I also notice that "picture" only contains the first image in the database.

I could put this database query in a function using "WHERE RECORDID=..." and loop it manually building the table returning "picture" each time, but Id like to avoid running a function 100 times, esp one that access a database.

Is it possible to read the whole database that contains images and just load it directly into a Datatable in one big swoop?

**EDIT: So I got this to work:**

```
    Dim strConnection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=SBS2257_ID.accdb;"
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT [RecordID], [LowRes] FROM [Records];"
    Using objConnection = New OleDbConnection(strConnection)
        Using objCommand = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, objConnection)
            Using objDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(objCommand)
                Dim objDataTable As New DataTable("IDs")
                objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataTable)
                Return objDataTable
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

how ever when I go to view row 0, col 1 which should be the first LowRes image via a .ToString Useing this code:

```
Private Sub PrintValues(ByVal table As DataTable)
    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
        For Each col As DataColumn In table.Columns
            MsgBox(row(col).ToString())
        Next col
    Next row
End Sub
```

It just displays "System.Byte[]". It knows its a Byte datatype, but how do I display that in a picturebox?

Comment: I think this question will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977554/vb-net-retrive-an-image-blob-from-mysql-db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ExecuteScalar()` executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query.

as your query is

```
Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT [RecordID], [LowRes] FROM [Records];"
```

the first column is `RecordID` which is not a `Byte()`.

you can change your query as following:

```
Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT [LowRes] FROM [Records];"
```

or you have to use other methods to get data from the database

```
Dim strSql As String = "SELECT [RecordID], [LowRes] FROM [Records]"
Dim dtb As New DataTable
Using cnn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    cnn.Open()
    Using dad As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, cnn)
        dad.Fill(dtb)
    End Using
    cnn.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: So is there a mass "ExecuteScalar()" to read and return multiple records with multiple fields of different datatypes?

Comment: the `ExecuteScalar` should be used for single item like as `SELECT Count(*) FROM Table1`. to read all data you can use `DataAdapter.Fill` as shown in updated answer

Comment: dtb comes up empty but I know its a valid query with data in the database.